# Understanding Cranium.js code

Tags: javascript

I was reading Cranium.js (https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/3769967) code by Addy Osmani and I could not understand what two lines of JavaScript do. The entire code is the following:

```
// Mix in to any object in order to provide it with custom events.
var Events = Cranium.Events = {
        channels: {},
        eventNumber: 0,
        trigger: function (events, data) {
            for (var topic in Cranium.Events.channels){
                if (Cranium.Events.channels.hasOwnProperty(topic)) {
                    if (topic.split("-")[0] == events){
                        Cranium.Events.channels[topic](data) !== false || delete Cranium.Events.channels[topic];
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        on: function (events, callback) {
            Cranium.Events.channels[events + --Cranium.Events.eventNumber] = callback;
        },
        off: function(topic) {
            delete Cranium.Events.channels[topic];
        }            
};
```

The first line I don't understand is:

```
if (topic.split("-")[0] == events){
                            Cranium.Events.channels[topic](data) !== false || delete Cranium.Events.channels[topic];
                        }
```

That is: I understand the if, what I don't get is what is happening inside curly braces. It seems to me (but I could be wrong) that if the left expression is true nothing happens, if not he deletes `Cranium.Events.channels[topic]`.

The second line I don't understand is:

```
Cranium.Events.channels[events + --Cranium.Events.eventNumber] = callback;
```

I don't understand the double minus sign.

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: so your questions is more generic "What does **||** and **--** mean?" - first is the normal `OR` taht translates to a normal `if` clause in this case as the left operation is a boolean one and the second is the same as `Cranium.Events.eventNumber = Cranium.Events.eventNumber - 1`, but because it's in the back, `--Cranium.Events.eventNumber` instead of `Cranium.Events.eventNumber--` it will count first and give you the number after the operation.

Comment: Maybe, what I don't get is the big picture: that is, I don't understand why he performs that subtraction. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (topic.split("-")[0] == events){
    Cranium.Events.channels[topic](data) !== false || delete Cranium.Events.channels[topic];
}
```

is the same as

```
if (topic.split("-")[0] == events){
    if ( Cranium.Events.channels[topic](data) === false ) {
        delete Cranium.Events.channels[topic];
    }
}
```

and in `Cranium.Events.channels[events + --Cranium.Events.eventNumber] = callback;` the `--` is subtracting 1 from `Cranium.Events.eventNumber` before applying it. So, if it was 3 before, it would be 2 as it is added to `events`.

Comment: Your second `if` is missing the `=== false` check. The original callback could return `undefined`, `0` or other falsy values without tripping the `delete`.